# Custom (or latest) npm version in Google Cloud Builder

Tags: npm, google-container-builder, google-cloud-build

I'm using Google Cloud Builder (GCB) to build some Node.js code. I'm using npm's new `package-lock.json` feature to pin dependencies. This works best when using the `npm ci` command that was introduced in `npm@5.7.1`. Unfortunately, all of [GCB's npm images](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/cloud-builders/GLOBAL/npm?gcrImageListsize=50) are currently set to `npm@5.6.0`

How can I use a different npm version in GCB without creating a custom builder image?

Edit: It may not be the case that all of GCB's images are set to `npm@5.6.0`, but the one that I need to use (`node-8.11.0`) is set to this version.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by creating my own container image based on the cloud-builder's npm image.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-8.11.0

ARG NPM_VERSION
RUN npm i -g npm@${NPM_VERSION}

ENTRYPOINT ["npm"]
```

cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args:
  - 'build'
  - '--build-arg=NPM_VERSION=latest'
  - '--tag=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/npm:latest'
  - '.'

images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/npm:latest'
```

I ran `gcloud builds submit . --config=cloudbuild.yaml` from the same folder containing the `Dockerfile` and `cloudbuild.yaml` files. This submitted the build to GCB and posted an image in my project's container registry. I then used this image in my other project's `cloudbuild.yaml` that needed the upgraded npm version, like so:

```
steps:
- id: frontend_install
  name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/npm:latest'
  args: ['ci']
  waitFor: ['-']
```

After doing this, everything works as expected.